# how to create an algorithm for counting in pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm

```
import pandas as pd
```

Create a dataframe for an example problem:

```
data = [[['A','B','C','D','E'],1000],
[['C','B'],2000],
[['X','Y','Z'],3000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['token','view'])
```

what does he look like:

```
In[0]:df
Out[0]:

              token view
0   [A, B, C, D, E] 1000
1   [C, B]          2000
2   [X, Y, Z]       3000
```

Now the main problem, I need to count the number of views for all unique values in each of the lists that are in the column df['token']. That is if the letter "B" is repeated in two rows with views 1000,2000 then I will get the sum of 3000. I created a code that counts the sum of these views, but it does not work correctly. Below I have shown an example of my code and what I would like to get

We create a list with all letters and convert it to a set and back to get only unique values without repetitions:

```
lst = []
for item in df['token']:
    for it in item:
        lst.append(it)
set_token = set(lst)
unique_token = list(set_token)
```

This is how it will look like:

```
In[1]:unique_token
Out[1]:
['D', 'E', 'Z', 'B', 'A', 'Y', 'C', 'X']
```

Now create a dictionary with keys from unique values and assign each 0 views as the initial value:

```
dict_token = {}
for item in unique_token:
    dict_token[item] = 0
```

This is how it will look like:

```
In[2]:dict_token
Out[2]:
{'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'Z': 0, 'B': 0, 'A': 0, 'Y': 0, 'C': 0, 'X': 0}
```

Now I created code to calculate the sum of views for each value in a unique dictionary if it occurs in a string. But I can't get the value of df['view'] for the same row that is currently being iterated over and I get a series, and an incorrect count, how to fix it? below is an option what I would like to get at the end

```
for item in dict_token.keys():
    for it in df['token']:
        if item in it:
            dict_token[item] += df['view']
```

and i get:

```
In[3]:dict_token
Out[3]:
{'D': 0    2000
 1    4000
 2    6000
 Name: view, dtype: int64,
 'E': 0    2000
 1    4000
 2    6000
 Name: view, dtype: int64,
 'Z': 0    2000
 1    4000
 2    6000
 Name: view, dtype: int64,
 'B': 0     4000
 1     8000
 2    12000
 Name: view, dtype: int64,
 'A': 0    2000
 1    4000
 2    6000
 Name: view, dtype: int64,
 'Y': 0    2000
 1    4000
 2    6000
 Name: view, dtype: int64,
 'C': 0     4000
 1     8000
 2    12000
 Name: view, dtype: int64,
 'X': 0    2000
 1    4000
 2    6000
 Name: view, dtype: int64}
```

but i want:

```
Out[3]:{'D': 1000, 'E': 1000, 'Z': 3000, 'B': 3000, 'A': 1000, 'Y': 3000, 'C': 3000, 'X': 3000}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with pandas? `df.explode('token').groupby('token').agg(TotalViews=('views', 'sum'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) your lists, then compute the [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and convert [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) :

```
df.explode('token').groupby('token')['view'].sum().to_dict()
```

output: `{'A': 1000, 'B': 3000, 'C': 3000, 'D': 1000, 'E': 1000, 'X': 3000, 'Y': 3000, 'Z': 3000}`